# Data Clone Error

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to do tabindexing for a course which has been developed using pHp HTML5 jQuery. There is a video link on a page which works fine when I remove the tab index of that page, but when I start putting the tab index in the following manner

```
$("#id").attr("tabindex",i);
```

where i varies from 1 to number of last element present on the page I see a weird error in the console which says

```
 DataCloneError: The object could not be cloned.return window.JSON.parse( data);
```

Also note that the video opens in a popup

Please let me know what does this error mean.
Thanks

Comment: can you share your html code? so that it can help us to find the exact issue.

Comment: no there is no duplicate tabindex